# starting Autoingestion tool from Excel VBA macro in a special directory called "- iPhone"

Tags: java, vba, command-line, terminal

I have written a little Excel VBA report tool for my iPhone App sales.

To make it easier to use I would like to use the Autoingestion tool from Apple.

The Autoingestion tool from Apple gets activated like this (it's a Java class) from the command line

```
java Autoingestion john@xyz.com letmein 80012345 Sales Daily Summary 20100204
```

How can I run this from within an VBA macro which would have to basically do this

```
cd - iPhone     <- this I dont know how to do correctly, since it always takes the "-" as a command, the directory name is "- iPhone"

java Autoingestion john@xyz.com letmein 80012345 Sales Daily Summary 20100204
```

There are basically two questions:

**1. how to change into a directory called "- iPhone"?**

**2. how to launch a Java class command from inside Excel VBA**

ps. I am using a MAC to do all this.

ps. I also tried cd "- iPhone" in the terminal, but this does not work either
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

1. `cd -- "- iPhone"`, the double-dash tells `cd` that it's options end there, and directory names follow.
2. Use the `shell(command [, windowStyle])` call from the VBA API.

`Shell("cd -\ iPhone && java AutoIngest ...")` is probably around what you'd be looking for. If it doesn't work this way, try wrapping that in a `sh -c "commands..."` for the `Shell` call.

Comment: I just tried it again. created a folder named "- x" with exactly one space - but cd "- x" does not work. The error is -bash: cd: - : invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir].  I also tried the shell command in VBA, but I do not know how to combine the "cd... & java Autoingest ..." in one cmd. Even when I do only a simple shell("pwd") in VBA I get a run time error '53'

Comment: I also tried cd "-\ x"
-bash: cd: -\: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir] - but I get same error

Comment: super, this really works Thanks! (I also have tried many things - without success). Do you have any idea why I keep getting the run time error 53 for even a simple shell("pwd")?

Comment: Shell will expect the string you pass it starts with the path to an executable (you may have to specify full path - not sure), when doing `Shell("pwd")`, you're trying to have it run a shell built-in (e.g. not an actual binary program), and thus you get Runtime Error 56 (File not found). Again, use `/usr/bin/sh -c "commands"` if you really need to do that.

Comment: FYI if the application is in the PATH environment variable, you wouldn't need to specify the full path.

Comment: @JP. It's true if it's in the launchd-time PATH environment... But not if it's only in a shell PATH. I've been biten by this a lot - and generally I consider it's safer for an app to not trust the environment (especially PATH) too much...